# How to clone a GIT instance that is on a DEV server?

Tags: git, ssh

I am somewhat new to GIT. I have been provided a dev instance to which I SSH onto. The DEV instance can do GIT pull and GIT push.

```
The instructions given to me are:
git clone git@jira.somedomain.com:/SomeProject
cd SomeProject
git remote add dev git@jira.somedomain.com:/SomeProject
git config --global user.email "<your_email>"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Since I do development on my local machine, I want to be able to do a GIT clone and do GIT push and GIT pull.

Problem is when I do:

```
git clone git@jira.somedomain.com:/SomeProject
cd SomeProject
git remote add dev git@jira.somedomain.com:/SomeProject
git config --global user.email "<your_email>"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

my user name and password do not work.

Also when I do

```
git clone MYUSERNAME@jira.somedomain.com:/SomeProject
cd SomeProject
git remote add dev git@jira.somedomain.com:/SomeProject
git config --global user.email "<your_email>"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

it still does not work even though I have a password to my JIRa account.

Any tips?

Comment: user name and password do not work in what sense?  What error message do you get, after which command?

Comment: Permission denied, please try again. I get that after I try: git clone MYUSERNAME@jira.somedomain.com:/SomeProject  OR git clone git@jira.somedomain.com:/SomeProject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user.email and user.name fields in git-config are used to put your name into the commit objects, they're not used to authenticate the SSH connection. This is normally done using SSH keys.

Github has instructions for [Mac](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/), [Windows](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) and [linux](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/) on how to set these up on your workstation. The "paste your public key into Github" step doesn't apply; in this case, you'll have to put it into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the user `git` on your `jira.somedomain.com` server.